# How to remove bitterness of bittergourd?

Tags: flavor, vegetables

How can we remove the bitterness out of bittergourd? If we cannot remove it, Are there any ways to reduce bitterness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soaking cut slices of bitter gourd in salt water/brine helps reduce the bitterness. I do not recommend scraping the surface and removing the seeds because that's the nutritious part of the gourd. It is better to keep it intact and reduce the bitterness by soaking in brine. Usually 30 mins is good enough to reduce the bitterness. And always while cooking try to use something acidic, like lemon juice or tamarind extract to enhance the flavor and reduce the bitterness. Another point to remember is the bitterness reduces as the food cools down, so it's better to keep these dishes ready before serving.

Answer (score 2):

you can remove bitterness from bitter gourd by using the following tips.
Scrape Off The Rugged Surface.
Remove big seeds Use Salt.
Rub the slices with lots of salt and keep aside for 30 minutes before cooking.
Squeeze The Juice.
Squeeze out the juice from the bitter gourd Use Diluted Yogurt.
Use large amount of tomato it help to dilute the bitterness .